# Laravel 5.3 Amazon s3 upload issue

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, laravel-5.3

So I've been working on a project recently and I've managed to get stuck trying to upload a file to s3, I've done this before on previous sites and it's been fine but this one seems to proving a little tricky.

I'm trying to upload a file (pdf) that's been sent through a form to my 'horsebeach' bucket on s3, after clicking submit on the form, the page just freezes.

Here's my upload code:

```
 $file = $request->file('attachment');
 $s3 = Storage::disk('s3');
 $s3->put($file->hashName(), file_get_contents($file));
```

Inside my EventController:

```
public function newEvent(Request $request){
      // in here
}
```

Changing to local storage works just fine and the file is stored in my app storage.

Here's my form incase that helps:

```
<form action="{{URL::to('events/new')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form_inputs clearfix">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span2">
                <label class="control-label">Event Title:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="span10">
                <input type="text" name="event-title" placeholder="Event Title" class="span11"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @if ($errors->has('event-title'))
    <span class="help-block">
        <strong>{{ $errors->first('event-title') }}</strong>
    </span>
    @endif
    <div class="form_inputs clearfix">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span2">
                <label class="control-label">Begin Date:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="span2">
                <input type="text" name="begin-date" placeholder="e.g 27-02-2016" class="span11 dpicker">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @if ($errors->has('begin-date'))
    <span class="help-block">
        <strong>{{ $errors->first('begin-date') }}</strong>
    </span>
    @endif
    <div class="form_inputs clearfix">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span2">
                <label class="control-label">End Date:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="span2">
                <input type="text" name="end-date" placeholder="e.g 27-02-2016" class="span11 dpicker">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @if ($errors->has('end-date'))
    <span class="help-block">
        <strong>{{ $errors->first('end-date') }}</strong>
    </span>
    @endif
    <div class="form_inputs clearfix">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span2">
                <label class="control-label">Location:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="span10">
                <input type="text" name="location" placeholder="e.g Dave's house" class="span11"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @if ($errors->has('location'))
    <span class="help-block">
        <strong>{{ $errors->first('location') }}</strong>
    </span>
    @endif
    <div class="form_inputs clearfix">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span2">
                <label class="control-label">Fee:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="span10">
                <div class="input-prepend">
                    <span class="add-on">£ </span> <input type="text" id='fee' name="fee" placeholder="2000" style="width: 87%">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @if ($errors->has('fee'))
    <span class="help-block">
        <strong>{{ $errors->first('fee') }}</strong>
    </span>
    @endif
    <div class="form_inputs clearfix">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span2">
                <label class="control-label">Colour:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="span10">
                <div class="input-prepend">
                    <input type="text" name="colour" placeholder="" id="color1" class="color1">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @if ($errors->has('colour'))
    <span class="help-block">
        <strong>{{ $errors->first('colour') }}</strong>
    </span>
    @endif
    <div class="form_inputs clearfix">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span2">
                <label class="control-label">Description:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="span10">
                <textarea rows="3" name="description" placeholder="What's going down?" class="span11 elastic"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form_inputs clearfix">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span2">
                <label class="control-label">Confirmed?</label>
            </div>
            <div class="span10">
                <input type="checkbox" name="confirmed" class="radio1">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form_inputs clearfix">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span2">
                <label class="control-label">Attachments:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="span10">
                <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="attachment"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form_inputs">
        <input type="submit" name="create-event" value="Create Event" class="btn btn-info"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Config file:

```
    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key'    => env('AWS_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET'),
        'region' => env('AWS_LOCATION'),
        'bucket' => 'horsebeach',
    ],
```

composer.json:

```
"league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "~1.0"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you make sure to pull in `aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel`?

I have the following installed in my project:

```
    "aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel": "^3.1",
    "graham-campbell/flysystem": "^3.0",
    "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3":"~1.0",
```

Also, tail your `storage/logs/laravel.log` to see whats going on.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have the same require's in my composer.json. After tailing I''ve noticed this '[2016-09-10 23:25:27] local.ERROR: exception 'Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception' with message 'Error executing "ListObjects" on "https://s3.ireland.amazonaws.com/horsebeach?prefix=24f87dc6e0de13243f30199798095eb3.pdf%2F&max-keys=1&encoding-type=url"; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 7: Failed to connect to s3.ireland.amazonaws.com port 443: Operation timed out (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)''

Comment: Timed out error, so verify that your key, secret and region are all correct in your `.env`

Comment: OK I got it, stupid mistake really. I had Ireland as my region, then it hit me that the region is actually eu-west-1 for Ireland. All working fine now.